# Class design: how to add sequencing or alternating logic to API

Tags: c++, design-patterns

My classes are like this:

```
class FB_I {
  public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class TEE_I {
  public:
    virtual void tee() = 0;
};

class C: public FB_I, public TEE_I {
  public:
    virtual void foo();
    virtual void tee();
};
```

Now I realize that foo() and bar() are actually not totally independent, foo() must be called before bar().

I wonder what is the best solution to handle this given the following:

1. I do not want to add logic in C::foo() and C::tee() to catch out of order calling.
2. I can use the solution as a pattern to handle another case, foo() and bar() are alternative API: when one is called, the other should not be.

Comment: How will you catch if something is called or not without adding that logic? Even if there was a feature for it, it would internally do that.
And also there is no place you override bar with a valid virtual function. You should handle the both scenarios with providing appropriate well written documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), sometimes known as a [Non-Virtual Interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface):

```
struct FB_I {
    void baz() {
        foo();
        bar();
    }
private:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;    
};
```

Comment: +1 Another approach would be to define foo() and bar() with the appropriate logic, and have them call doFoo() and doBar() respectively.